# PHP to XML insert array

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML string that I have built up using the following example:

```
//add root
$Add = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Add')); 
//pCase
$pCase = $Add->appendChild($dom->createElement('pCase')); 

//add elements
$LeadGenID = $pCase->appendChild($dom->createElement('LeadGenID'));
$LeadGenID->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('22'));

$Debtor = $pCase->appendChild($dom->createElement('Debtor'));
//address fields
$Addresses = $Debtor->appendChild($dom->createElement('Addresses'));
$Address = $Addresses->appendChild($dom->createElement('Address'));
//array of address objects should go here

$test1 = $dom->saveXML();
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($test1);

if ($sxe === false) {
echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}

    $dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($sxe);
    if (!$dom_sxe) {
       echo 'Error while converting XML';
       exit;
    }

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $dom_sxe = $dom->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
    $dom_sxe = $dom->appendChild($dom_sxe);

    echo $dom->save('application.xml');
```

This then outputs the following in my XML:

```
<Add>
<pCase>
    <LeadGenID>22</LeadGenID>
    <Debtor>
        <Addresses><Address/></Addresses>
    </Debtor>
</pCase>
```

I also need to output an array into this XML, so that the full output is as follows:

```
<Add>
<pCase>
    <LeadGenID>22</LeadGenID>
    <Debtor>
        <Addresses>
            <Address>
                <Street>Some street</Street>
                <Postcode>Some postcode</Postcode>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </Debtor>
</pCase>
```

I have tried to accomplish this using

```
$address_array = array (
    $_POST['Street'] => 'Street',
    $_POST['Postcode'] => 'Postcode'
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Address/>');
array_walk_recursive($address_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
```

but at this point I am completely lost. The API I have been given is sparse on documentation to say the least but I'm getting closer with it, but I need to enter the address as an array for the gateway.  I am new to PHP as I am primarily a frontend developer who has usually only done simple contact forms etc in PHP.

How can I output the XML example I've given above?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code blocks with the `{}` toolbar button. I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: What is `$Address`? And why are you mixing two different PHP XML APIs?

Comment: Sorry $Address is one of the nodes in my XML.  This may not have been clear, I only put in a short example so you could see what code I was using.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It might help if you remove what you need, but more what you want in concrete as output, how your current output looks like and which error messages you get in specific. The random code you've posted with a somewhat weird description does not really pose any answerable question. Please improve.

Comment: Ok I've edited the original question to hopefully make things clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Random weird stuff I've spot:

- You start with `new SimpleXMLElement('<Address/>')` but your root node is `<Addresses>`
- An `$Address` variable pops up from nowhere
- A `$dom` object pops up from nowhere
- You call `createTextNode()` which:

  1. It isn't a SimpleXML method but a DOMDocument method
  2. Expects a string as argument but it's fed with a `SimpleXMLElement` instance
  3. Creates a **text** node

Comment: Ok - so how can I insert the array as per the example I gave above? The root node is 'Addresses' with another node under this called 'Address', which would be an object in the array or a collection of address information.  Would it be better if I gave a XML example of exactly what I was trying to achieve?

Comment: You could start by fixing the known issues. Injecting random code until it works can take quite long to succeed.

Comment: Can I not use SimpleXMLElement in this context then?  I will address your points and post back.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes/
It is a very small and simple to use library, if you just need array to xml.